# Cucumber tests with XML payload - Dynamic payload changes

Tags: spring-boot-test, cucumber-java

I am working on test automation where we are writing Cucumber test cases for a REST service which takes in XML requests.
I am trying to prepare a setup where I dont want to keep Models and Test XMLs is Automation project as we have number of services and project is run in build pipeline.

I currently have below setup :-

| testScenario  | System-Id | Request-Id | filename | status |

| verify API without header |           | 12341 | success.xml | 200    |

| verify API with invalid payload | XXX  | 12345  | invalid_parameter_namevalue.xml | 500    |

I am reading file in dataFactory class with :-

return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(Filepath + filename)));

Anyone have better solutions to handle this?
I would very much like a approach where I can handle the test data on the fly.

I have tried converting XML in Map class, but it fails as XML request is expected to have repetitive elements which had attributes in name-value pair. Only last element is mapped.